# pg_dump and pg_restore can't deal with file name contain Arabic fonts

Tags: postgresql, filenames

I use Postgres 10, and pg_dump\pg_restore that come with it.
now pg_dump and pg_restore give me an error when trying to dump\restore a file or a path that hold Arabic fonts(didn't test any font except English & Arabic)

Here's the exception for trying to restore a file name that has no English (like Arabic) characters.

```
.\pg_dump.exe --file "C:\א\TOC.DUMP" --host "localhost" --port "1111" --username "MyUserName" --verbose --format=c --blobs --compress "1" --schema "MySchema" "MyDBName"
```

> System.Exception: pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not open input
> file "C:\?\TOC.DUMP":
> Invalid argument

And the same Exception when the file path has Arabic Fonts.

Everything works fine when using English Fonts for FileName\FilePath.

So I searched here and on google and PostgreSQL Documentation, and couldn't find a related subject except for the fact that  pg_dump\pg_restore have no problem dealing with scripts that hold Arabic & Hebrew Encoding,
but nothing was mentioned about the encoding of the file name itself.

how did I solve it? I didn't.
I couldn't stop shipping my projects because of this issue.

so as a temporary workaround, I prevent the user from using Arabic fonts
with this code down here, it's not a good way of doing things you know.

```
            // C#
            BackUpPath = fileDialog.FileName;
    
            var westernLatin = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
            var arabic = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
    
            var bytes = arabic.GetBytes(BackUpPath);
            var result = westernLatin.GetString(bytes);
     
            if (result != BackUpPath)
            {
            // Inform user to use English fonts for the file name and file path.
            }
```

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: The problem might be that `cmd` uses a different encoding from the rest of Windows. When dealing with encoding problems, try to find the actual byte values that constitute the characters. Either is the mismatch there, or `client_encoding` is set wrong.

Comment: laurenz-albe
You were absolutely right, it's a Console thing,
While the code_page of the Console is set to 437 (United States),
this code page was the problem here, setting it on the Console to UTF-8 get reset after close and reopen the console,
setting it from local as you implied was successful,
now i'm in the way of figuring out how to do it in code,
going to try setting the code page in the Process i created to work on pg_dump\pg_restore, and see.
You were too helpful, Many thanks .

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I tried giving the process argument many different encoding
Arguments = Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(args));
still no success.
maybe pg_dump and pg_restore use a strict encoding internally for the arguments, idk.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to set the environment variable `PGCLIENTENCODING` to the encoding used in your `cmd`, not sure.

Comment: LaurenzAlbe: As you expected, setting PGCLIENTENCODING to any encoding doesn't make any change.

Comment: I am out of my depth in these Windows waters. Can you invoke `chcp` from your script to change `cmd`'s encoding?

Comment: Tried that in the arguments i send to pg_dump, the error returned say that pg_dump does not know this chcp, my working arguments to pg_dump are like this
'                string args = $@"-Fc {BackupFullOrSchema} -b -h {BackupArgs.Host} -p {BackupArgs.Port} -d {BackupArgs.TargetDatabase} -U {BackupArgs.User} -f {BackupArgs.FileDumpPath}";
'
'                ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                pInfo.FileName = pg_dumpPath;
                pInfo.Arguments = args;
..........'

Comment: Now i did this: started cmd, chcp 1256(and other codepages), then cd to pg_dump dir, called pg_dumb.exe args, it all work with english Chars and save the english FileName dump successfully, yet when using Arabic FileName(or a path with some Arabic Chars) it strill give me error, pg_dump still see it as ?????? Chars, Erro is like (pg_dump: [custom archiver] could not open output file C:\Temp\?????.bak": Invalid argument).

Comment: Hey @UsamaSafi did you solve this?

Comment: No @ShaharShokrani and I don't know if it's fixed in the new versions of pg_dump\pg_restore.

Comment: Could you please have a look on the other question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70567560/6844481

Comment: @ShaharShokrani, I saw your question, I assume that pgAdmin change the weird character(s) to another Encoding that can work for your system, in your case I guess pgAdmin changes it to 0x0F04, a UTF-16 Encoding, but pg-dump and pg-restore don't do that, even changing the codepage of the console don't help, you mostly end with ???? instead.