# How does the pgadmin encodes the file path in backups?

Tags: postgresql, encoding, pgadmin, pg-dump, pg-restore

I'm trying to restore dump files from locations that contain character from other languages besides English.

So here is what I did:

From inside the `pgadmin` I used the backup tool like:

[image]

And inside the `FileName` input provided an actual real folder named "א":

`C:\א\toc.dump`

[image]

The actual file argument (`-f file`) has been auto decoded into:

[image]
`pg_dump.exe --file "C:\\0F04~1\\TOC~1.DUM"`

My question is what is the decoding system pgadmin uses in order to decode the file path argument?

**How did it came up with `0F04~1` from `א`?**

I'm asking it because pg_restore is not supporting file path that contains not English chars (from cmd):

```
pg_dump.exe --file "C:\\0F04~1\\TOC1.DUMP" .... WORKS OK!

pg_dump.exe --file "C:\\א\\TOC1.DUMP" ... Not Working!
```

> pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not open input file "..."

As in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63663532/6844481), so if I'll find the encoding system for pgadmin I'll use it from code.

My goal is to encode the path that contain not-English chars from a batch code so it will work.

Comment: Hey there, did you solve this yet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not something weird pgadmin does, but rather it is something weird Windows itself does when needing to represent such file names in a DOS-like setting.  Like when the name is more than 8 chars, or extension more than 3.

In my hands the weird presentation is only there in the logs and status messages.  If I use the GUI file chooser, the file names look normal, and replay successfully.

If you really want to know what Windows is doing, I think that is a better question for superuser with a Windows tag.  I don't know why you can't restore these files.  Are you using the pgAdmin GUI file chooser or trying to type the names in directly to something?

Comment: Hey @jjanes, thank you for your answer, see the updated question, the point is that when firing the pg_dump from cmd with א does not working and the encoded path works ok